# If I am on browser (self created) and when I click on back the page comes out of the layout instead of that, it back to previous page

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle abc){
    super.onCreate(abc);
    setContentView(R.layout.movie);

    WebView ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().getAllowFileAccess();
    ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());
    ourBrow.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    try{
        ourBrow.loadUrl("http://in.bookmyshow.com/pune/movies");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please suggest me some code that will help me for building my app.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem you are having?

Comment: Override onBackPressed and have it do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
    switch(keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        }else{
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```